# Представление данных JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, chart.js

Доброе времени суток. Имеется некий набор json данных:

```
[{
"timestamp": "Monday",
"original_tweet": "756",
"retweets": "345",
"shared": "34",
"quoted": "14"},{
"timestamp": "Tuesday",
"original_tweet": "756",
"retweets": "345",
"shared": "34",
"quoted": "14"}, {"timestamp": "Wednesday",
"original_tweet": "756",
"retweets": "345",
"shared": "34",
"quoted": "14"}]
```

Необходимо выводить данные в виде : Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday, чтобы построить график

```
var data = {
labels: test,
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: сюда вводить данные
    }
]
```

};

Вот что имею

```
  $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'servlet',
              data: {queryDataStart:query,query:dataEnd,open:open},
              response:'json',



                success:function (data) {
                 $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(indice, list){
                        alert(list.name);
            });



              }



          });
```

Выводит(в alert отдельными сообщениями, а нужно строкой):
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
При построении графика возвращает только Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понимаю то вам нужно просто собрать строку, а потом уже отправить ее в alert

```
var names = [];
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(indice, list){
    names.push(list.name);
});
alert(names.join(', '));
```